# Limit the number of time a form can be submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea:

```
      <form id='test'>
      <textarea class='test2'> </textarea> <input type='submit' value='send'/>
      </form>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of times a user can submit the textarea (for example, 5 times per minute).

EDIT:
   I would like to do that on client-side, in Javascript.

EDIT 2:

It is for a chat. I just don't want people to be able to post too many messages within a small lap of time. So it's not a problem if they refresh their page to get ride of the limit, the time they'll take to do it is long enough...

Comment: Submitted where? To a database? What server side language are you using?

Comment: Do you want to do this in JavaScript (can be worked around quite easily, but may be faster in UI terms) or on the server?

Comment: Do you want the limit on the client or server side?

Comment: How important is this? eg if it's just to stop casual users, some form of javascript would be sufficient. If it's a more strict requirement, it should be server-side code (bypassing js restrictions is trivial). Also, you may need to consider how to identify each user - what if they use 2 different browsers / 2 different PCs?

Comment: in Javasript. I don't need to do it on the server.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to set a cookie for the user on submit then when the cookie hits your specified number don't allow it to submit.

Comment: @BillyMoat that's true but also include a timestamp for the first of those so you can run a sliding window

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store some variables:

```
$(function () {
   var timesSubmitted = 0;
   var maxSubmits = 5;
   var intervalMilliseconds = 10000; // for testing   
   var interval;   
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function (event) {
        if (!interval) {
            interval = setTimeout(function () {
                interval = undefined;
                timesSubmitted = 0;
                $('div').append('TIMER RESET. Submit again.<br />')
            }, intervalMilliseconds);
        }
        timesSubmitted ++;
        if (timesSubmitted > maxSubmits) {
            $('div').append('NO GO YO!<br />')
        } else {
            $('div').append('valid<br />')   
        }
        event.preventDefault();        
    });        
});​
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ppLP/)

Answer (score 1):

Like they said, it's not professional, nor secure to do this with javascript. Better server-side, but here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var flag = false;
function checkTimer(){
    if (flag){
        flag=false;
        return true;
    }
    alert("Don't flood man!");
    return false;
}

//12 seconds, max 5 times per minute
setTimeout(function(){flag=true;},12000);
</script>
```

And on the form:

```
<form id='test' onSubmit="return checkTimer()">
```

Comment: And once the form submits and the page reloads? You'll lose all your variables. (Sorry to be negative on your first post and welcome to SO!)

Comment: @Basic Hehehe, thanks! I'm always here but didn't comment.
I first thought a setTimer instead of setTimeout, but... indeed page reloads, so condition only affects the first 12 seconds. This works, try it. Another story is if form is sent by ajax, not this case.

Answer (score 1):

I made this quick little sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xh4h/7/). You are probably going to need to warp this in some ajax so you can submit the form without reloading the variables to retain your information.

If you are looking for the AJAX version it would look something

> ```
> // Setup variable for easy tracking!!!
> var timesSubmitted = 0, timeCounter = 60 * 1000, Timer = null;
>
> // Call function to submit form
> function submitForm() {
>   // Check if user has submitted form more than 5 times
>   if (timesSubmitted < 5) {
>       // Call ajax to submit form. jQuery Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
>       $.ajax({
>           type: "POST",
>           url: 'ajaxpage.html',
>           data: { test2: $('#test textarea').val() },
>           success: function(data) { // if form is submitted successfully
>               // If timer has yet to be started... Start it! 
>               if (Timer === null) {
>                   Timer = setTimeout(
>                       function() {  
>                           // Setup alert so user knows they can continue to submit form
>                           if (timesSubmitted > 0) { alert('Submissions Reset'); }
>                           timesSubmitted = 0; 
>                       }, 
>                   timeCounter );
>               }
>
>               // Add for submission to counter
>               timesSubmitted++;
>             }
>       });
>   }else{
>       // Alert user they can not sumbit anymore!
>       alert('You may only submit this from 5 times per minute!');
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to limit this on client side (you could try to use JavaScript to enforce such limit but it can be easily ommited by disabling JS). You can enforce such limit on your target script and refuse form processing if it comes to often

Comment: There is no way to set a +1 counter each time the user click on the submit button, and once the counter reaches 5 the user can't click on it anymore?

Comment: what happens when the user refreshes the page if it's only done with javascript? you could store the info in a cookie, but that would be lost if the cookies expired or were cleared.